# Custom shell - how to read in a script for execution?

Tags: c, shell

I am building a custom shell in C and have implemented pipe, fork and file redirection support. I want to enable scripting support so that my shell can be invoked non-interactively as follows:

```
yosh foo.sh
```

or

```
./bar.sh
```

where bar.sh has the shebang `#!/bin/yosh`

Should I start by reading in the script file which will be passed as a command line arg to my shell? Is there a need to fork a process for each line in the `foo.sh` script? Currently, the shell is coded to be interactive with a giant while loop.

Any help/ideas are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You _can't_ fork a process for each line and have the effects of those lines persist when they're invoking builtins (like `cd`) that change the state of the shell itself. Also, you don't generally want to treat things as _lines_ at all -- think in terms of compound commands and simple commands; or better, start with the [grammar specified in the POSIX sh standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

Comment: If the standard's discussion of tokenization &c isn't familiar to you, take a compiler design class before coming back to this project.